# Unexpected representation for class's instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
    
    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
         return cls(0, 0)


point = Point.zero()
```

I am not getting the expected output: `Point(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the correct `Point` object. To confirm, print `type(point)` and print `point.x` or `point.y`. But its representation defaults to what `object.__repr__` provides(all classes inherit this from `object` class). Implement your own `__str__` or `__repr__`. (See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/13944524)):

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        return cls(0, 0)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Point{self.x, self.y}"


point = Point.zero()
print(point)
```

Answer (score -1):

You do, but what you generate is a Class Object:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        return cls(0, 0)

origin = Point.zero()

origin.x -> 0
origin.y -> 0
```